# Is there any reference to tensorflow datasets compatibility chart (specifically tensorflow-gpu==2.10)

Tags: tensorflow

I wanted to install tensorflow datasets with pip and I cannot find a version that is compatible with tensorflow-gpu==2.10.

Unfortunately, wsl is broken on my PC and conda is also not throwing some random error.

I ahve tried installing tensorflow-datasets versions 1.0.1, 3 and 4 and all of them installed protobuf 2.23.4 which is incompatible with tensorflow==2.10. I had to subsequently downgrade protobuf. This issue happens with all the tensorflow-datasets I installed using pip.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out, stuck in a similar situation

Comment: Not really, I finally gave in and used keras datasets. I will try the answer below later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is protobuf version glitch between tensorflow 2.10 and the tensorflow-datasets while installing these package. To resolve this error , you need to install `protobuf 3.20` explicitly which is compatible with both the packages `Tensorflow 2.10` and `Tensorflow-datasets`.

First install both the packages which will install different protobuf versions

```
pip install tensorflow==2.10
pip install tensorflow-datasets  #This will install latest TF datasets version(4.9.2)
```

then install **protobuf 3.20**  as below:

```
pip install protobuf==3.20
```

Now restart the kernel and verify if you can import both the module by checking its version details

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.__version__.    #Output: '2.10.0'

import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
tfds.__version__.  #Output: '4.9.2'
```

Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) for TF install with GPU in Win OS.